# How to populate an ArrayList as a property inside a class using jdbc?

Tags: java, arraylist, jdbc

I have a frame which has two JComboBoxes and a *Rent* Button. One ComboBox contains an arraylist of a class called `Movie`. The other ComboBox contains an arraylist of a class called `Member` which has a property that's also an arraylist of `Movie` class.

The idea is to make a program with which I can rent movies to members. The members and movies are stored in an SQL database. I finished most of the work. The only thing I have left to do is code the logic in a way that the same `Member` can't rent the `Movie` they already currently rent. So no duplicate movies. My idea was to populate that `Movie` arraylist property inside a `Member` class and then see if that arraylist contains the movie selected in the movie combobox. If it does, I just display a `JOptionPane` with some error message. I tried to make a new moviesByMember list and then populate it with PreparedStatement with the parameter being the selected member in the members ComboBox but when I debug, the selected member index is `-1`.

My question is: how to populate that movie arraylist property? Or if there is another way of doing this?

This is the `Member` class:

```java
public class Member{

    private int Member_id;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    
    private String FullName;
    
    public ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        
        this.Member_id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
    
        return Member_id;
    }
    
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        
        this.FirstName= firstName;
    }
    
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        
        this.LastName= lastName;
    }
    
    public void setFullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        
        this.FullName = firstName + " " + LastName;
    }
    
    public String getFullName() {
        
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

This is the `Movie` class:

```java
public class Movie {

    private int Movie_id;
    private String Name;
    
    public int getId() {
        return Movie_id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.Movie_id = id;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And this is the frame in question:

```java
public class RentMovieFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    ArrayList<Member> members = new ArrayList<Member>();
    ArrayList<Movie> moviesByMember = new ArrayList<Movies>();
    SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection();
    JFrame rentMovieFrame = new JFrame();
    JButton rentMovieButton = new JButton();
    JComboBox<Member> membersComboBox = new JComboBox<Member>();
    JComboBox<Movie> moviesComboBox = new JComboBox<Movie>();
    JLabel memberLabel = new JLabel("Member:");
    JLabel movieLabel = new JLabel("Movie:");
    
    public RentMovieFrame(){
        
        rentMovieButton = new JButton();
        rentMovieButton.setBounds(200, 270, 200, 50);
        rentMovieButton.addActionListener(this);;
        rentMovieButton.setText("Rent Movie");
        rentMovieButton.setFocusable(false);
        
        memberLabel.setBounds(50, 50, 70, 50);
        memberLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        
        movieLabel.setBounds(50, 125, 70, 50);
        movieLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        
        membersComboBox.setBounds(150, 50, 300, 50);
        moviesComboBox.setBounds(150, 125, 300, 50);
        
        PopulateMoviesByMember(con.getConnectionValue());
        PopulateMembersComboBox();
        PopulateMoviesComboBox();
        
        rentMovieFrame.setTitle("Rent A Movie");
        rentMovieFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        rentMovieFrame.setLayout(null);
        rentMovieFrame.setSize(600, 400);
        rentMovieFrame.setVisible(true);
        rentMovieFrame.add(rentMovieButton);
        rentMovieFrame.add(membersComboBox);
        rentMovieFrame.add(moviesComboBox);
        rentMovieFrame.add(memberLabel);
        rentMovieFrame.add(movieLabel);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        if(e.getSource()==renMovieButton) {
            
            Member selectedMember = (Member)membersComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            Movie selectedMovie = (Movie)moviesComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            
            if(selectedMember.movies.stream().anyMatch(m -> m == selectedMovie)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This member already rents the selected 
                movie.");
            }
            else {
                RentAMovie(con.getConnectionValue());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Movie rented.");
            }
        }
        
        if(e.getSource()==membersComboBox) {
            PopulateMoviesByMember(con.getConnectionValue());
        }
    }
    
    private void PopulateMembersComboBox() {
        
        try {
            
            ResultSet res = null;
            Statement stm = con.getConnectionValue().createStatement();
            ListCellRenderer cellRenderer = new ListCellRenderer();
            
            String sql = "select * from Members";
            
            res = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            
            while(res.next()) {
                
                
                Member member = new Member();
                
                member.setId(res.getInt(1));
                member.setFirstName(res.getString(2));
                member.setLastName(res.getString(3));

                members.add(member);
            }
            
            for(Member member : members) {
                for(Movie movie : moviesByMember) {
                    member.movies.add(movie);
                }
                membersComboBox.addItem(member);
            }
            
            membersComboBox.setRenderer(cellRenderer);
            
            
            res.close();
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void PopulateMoviesByMember(Connection con) {
        
        try {
            
            ResultSet res = null;
            moviesByMember = new ArrayList<Movie>();
            int selectedMember = membersComboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
            
            PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select m.*"
                    + " from Members_Movies as mbm"
                    + " join Movies as m"
                    + " on mbm.Movie_id = m.Movie_id"
                    + " where mbm.Member_id = ?");
            
            pstm.setInt(1, selectedMember);
            
            res = pstm.executeQuery();
            
            while(res.next()) {
                
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                
                movie.setId(res.getInt("Movie_id"));
                film.setName(res.getString("Name"));
                
                moviesByMember.add(movie);
            }
            
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void PopulateMoviesComboBox() {
        
        try {
            
            ListCellRenderer cellRenderer = new ListCellRenderer();
            ResultSet res = null;
            Statement stm = con.getConnectionValue().createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from Movies";
            res = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            
            while(res.next()) {
                
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                
                movie.setId(res.getInt("Movie_id"));
                movie.setIme(res.getString("Name"));
                movies.add(movie);
            }
        
            for (Movie movie : movies) {
                moviesComboBox.addItem(movie);
            }
            
            moviesComboBox.setRenderer(cellRenderer);
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void RentAMovie(Connection con) {
        
        try {
            
            int selectedMember = (membersComboBox.getSelectedIndex()) + 1;
            int selectedMovie = (moviesComboBox.getSelectedIndex()) + 1;
            
            PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("insert into Members_Movies(Member_id, 
            Movie_id, Rent_Date)"
                    + " values (?, ?, GETDATE())");
            
            pstm.setInt(1, selectedMember);
            pstm.setInt(2, selectedMovie);
            
            pstm.executeUpdate();
            pstm.close();
            
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Divide your huge problem into smaller ones. One task to solve is: Get the data from the database (JDBC). The other one is: Send the data to the UI (Java Swing). For both you will find tutorials out there or answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have already retrieved the data for members and movies and put them in the comboboxes. I just don't know how to populate the movies arraylist thats inside the member class. When I try to do it in the PopulateMoviesByMember method, the parameter for the selectedMember index returns -1 and the moviesByMembers arraylist isn't populated.

Comment: Your code is [difficult](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) to read. Your method names look like bad class names

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, I just started Java and am getting used to conventions...